# Elasticsearch NEST using the Fields option

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

When using the Fieds options just to get a selection of fileds using the NEST client library and setting the Source(false), the Hits object's fields property is null.
How are we supposed to get access to the values returned if source is also null by setting Source(false).

Example:

```
var searchResponse =
await ElasticSearchConfig.GetClient().SearchAsync<Customers>(x => x.Index(indices)
.Size(1000)
  .Source(sr => sr
   .Includes(fi => fi
   .Fields(
       f => f.Id,
       f => f.Name,
       f => f.Age,   
       f => f.Address,
       f => f.DateRegistered
   )
   )).Source(false)
 .Query(q => q
             .Bool(bq =>
             bq.Filter(
               fq => fq.DateRange(t => t.Field(f => f.DateRegistered).LessThanOrEquals(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7).ToString("o"))))
             )));
```

Comment: Please share sample data of the index, in order to know more details about your use case. That helps to work on solution.